# Infinite loop, removing duplicates from a stack?

Tags: c++, stack, infinite-loop

I get an infinite loop when printing the new stack that's returned by removeDuplicates function, but I don't know what's causing it? All the other functions are working perfectly. The functions should keeps the first occurrence if the element is duplicated. This is the code:

```
class Stack { 
      Node *head; 

      public: Stack() { 
          head = NULL; 
      }; 

      ~Stack() {
          while (head) {
              Node * temp = head;
              head = head->next;
              delete temp;
          }
      }

      void push(int data); 
      int pop(); 
      bool isEmpty();
      void print();
      Stack removeDuplicates();
 }; 

 void Stack::push(int data) {
    Node *temp = new Node(data);
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
 }

 int Stack::pop() { 
    if (head != NULL ) {
        int x = head->data;
        Node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return x;
    } else {
        cout << "The stack is empty!";
        return -1;
    }
 }

 bool Stack::isEmpty(){
    return head == NULL;  
 } 

 void Stack::print() {
     Node * temp = head;
     while(temp != NULL ) {
         cout << temp->data << " ";
         temp = temp->next;
     }
 }

 Stack Stack::removeDuplicates(){
    Stack st;
    Node *temp = NULL;
    bool flag;

    while (head != NULL) {
        if (st.head == NULL) {
            st.push(head->data);
            temp = st.head;
        } else {
            flag = true;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                if (head->data == temp->data)
                    flag = false;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (flag == true)
               st.push(head->data);
         }
         Node *del = head;
         head = head->next;
         delete del;
     }
     return st;
 }
```

Comment: Please tell me you've tried stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: @AtlasC1 : `st.head` vs `head` ?

Comment: @AtlasC1 'st.head' is the new stack's head; while 'head' is the original stack's head.. How that would cause an error?

Comment: @norisknofun 'st.head' is the new stack's head; while 'head' is the original stack's head..?

Comment: Why don't you just post all the code pertaining to the stack and format it cleanly so people can really see what's going on instead of guessing about variables?  It's hard enough to debug when all the context is available.

Comment: Show us the definition of the Node class, please (I can guess but I'd rather see it)

Comment: Also, I edited your example to make it easier to read, can you accept the changes so I can see them?

Comment: Also, I recommend naming your flag something that indicates its use and intention. And you don't have to say if (flag == true), you can write if (flag). And the variable x, it's inconsistent with other naming. It too should reflect what it contains.

Comment: @1sand0s what do you recommend for the flag's name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is head declared as outside the function?

Does any code outside the function modify head?

If head is null going into the function then your function won't do anything, and depending on the print code you also didn't present, it might just loop forever for just that reason alone.

**In your first if statement you have if (st.head == NULL) ... and then you set temp to st.head, e.g. temp = NULL, so when is temp ever going to be non-null to use in the else branch of the if statement?**

Why don't you initialize all your variables explicitly inside the function instead of merely declaring them and associating them with types, since, if they're stack variables they are undefined.  It also helps to understand and maintain code if you format it so it is easier to parse visually.  You'd be surprised how many errors you can catch with that discipline.

```
  Stack Stack::removeDuplicates() {
    Stack st;
    Node *temp = NULL;
    bool flag;

    while (head != NULL) {
        if (st.head == NULL) {
            st.push(head->data);
            temp = st.head;
        } else {
            flag = true;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                if (head->data == temp->data)
                    flag = false;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (flag)
               st.push(head->data);
        }
        Node *del = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete del;
     }
     return st;
  }
```

Comment: You ask questions, these would belong to comments.

Comment: @usr1234567 For all the work and help I gave you don't think you're being a little draconian and petty? I did more to help than you did. You should lose points instead. Grow up.